# Part of LINQ query to seperate method (EF Core)

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I guess this has been asked before but i don't find any good examples. I have this query.

```
series = await query
    .GroupBy(o => new { o.AddedDate.Date.Month, o.AddedDate.Date.Year })
    .Select(g => new DateLineGraphItem 
        { Legend = new DateTime(g.Key.Year, g.Key.Month, 1), Number = g.Count() })
    .ToListAsync();
```

Everything is the same all the time except that my DB has different names for all the "AddedDate" column and i'm trying to figure out how i can break this out into it's own method, something like this.

```
List<DateLineGraphItem> series = GroupByAndSelect("AddedDate")
List<DateLineGraphItem> series = GroupByAndSelect("CreatedDate")
```

Do i have to use Expressions and Predicates and all that or it is possible to do in some simple manner?

Comment: The column is a string so you can make it a string variable like myDate.  You can add to the project configuration properties so in one project you can set myDate="AddedDate" and another project set myDate="CreatedDate"

Comment: that's not a linq thing. that's a db access thing. different db  names means different connections to make ie different EF classes ie separate Linqs queries.

Comment: @jdweng , dear i believe that's hack not a proper solution. in the end its up to the individual as well.

Comment: Suppose you had a database and the column name changed and you wanted to be backwards compatible?  In this case you have two dates : AddedDate and CreatedDate.  In some queries you may want to use either one and making the column name a variable would make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do i have to use Expressions

It's always better to use expressions (the whole LINQ is based on that concept) than magic strings. The only problem is that there is no out of the box solution for composing expressions from other expressions, so you need to write your own or use 3rd party packages.

From the other side, the `nameof` operator eliminates most of the `string` drawbacks. And EF Core provides a handy method called [EF.Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.ef.property?view=efcore-2.1) for simple scenarios like this.

So if the method contains `string propertyName` argument which points to direct property of type `DateTime`, you can simply replace the `o.AddedDate` with `EF.Property<DateTime>(o, propertyName)`, e.g.

```
series = await query
    .GroupBy(o => new { EF.Property<DateTime>(o, propertyName).Date.Month, EF.Property<DateTime>(o, propertyName).Date.Year })
    .Select(g => new DateLineGraphItem 
        { Legend = new DateTime(g.Key.Year, g.Key.Month, 1), Number = g.Count() })
    .ToListAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
You may extend your entity class using an interface which contains a DateTime Field, like this:

```
    public class EntityDb1 : IDatedEntity
    {
        public DateTime AddedDate { get; set; }

        public DateTime MyDate => AddedDate;
    }
    public class EntityDb2 : IDatedEntity
    {
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

        public DateTime MyDate => CreatedDate;
    }

    public interface IDatedEntity
    {
        DateTime MyDate{ get; }
    }
```

Then execute the query

```
        public class Test
        {
            public static async Task<IEnumerable<DateLineGraphItem>> ExecuteQuery(IQueryable<IDatedEntity> entityList)
            {
                return await entityList
                    .GroupBy(o =>new { o.MyDate.Date.Month, o.MyDate.Date.Year })
                    .Select(g => new DateLineGraphItem(){ Legend = new DateTime(g.Key.Year, g.Key.Month, 1), Number = g.Count() })
                    .ToListAsync();
            }
        }

        public class DateLineGraphItem
        {
            public DateTime Legend { get; set; }
            public int Number { get; set; }
        }
```